# 'BackgroundGeolocationPlugin' only refers to a type, but is being used a value here

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, cordova-plugins

I have an application in ionic and I want to integrate a background-geolocation plugin with npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation).

Before using version 2 of the plugin which allowed me to import the plugin into NgModule without problems, that version has not been possible to install for the following problem: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/258963/es-posible-instalar-una-versi%C3%B3n-que-ya-no-existe-de-un-paquete-npm

Now at the moment of using the current version of the new package, version 3.0.3, I have the following problem to declare the plugin in ngModule:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { BackgroundGeolocationPlugin } from '@mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    BackgroundGeolocationPlugin,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The plugin allows me to import an interface, not a class as usual.

For which I get the error when declaring it within `providers`: `'BackgroundGeolocationPlugin' only refers to a type, but is being used to value here. when trying to declare the plugin.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research, I discovered that my error was in the installation of the add-in, there was a package within the scope of integration (`@ionic-native`) of the original package with Ionic in which the add-in `@mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation` was correctly attached.

```
  ionic cordova plugin add @mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation
  npm install @ionic-native/background-geolocation@3.1.0-rc.1
```

Despite this I do not recommend the use of this plugin, I consider that it does not work properly and in turn causes problems with other installed plugins.

Comment: Appreciating you sharing answer to your own question ^^